# Euality between these two L1 integrable functions?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral

Let
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int |u_n v_n-uv| d \mu=0$$

I want to show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int u_n v_n d \mu=\int u v d \mu$$

What I have so far:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int u_n v_n d \mu-\int u v d \mu$$$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int u_n v_n d \mu-\lim_{n\to\infty}\int u v d \mu $$$$= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int u_n v_n-uv d \mu$$$$\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\int |u_n v_n-uv| d \mu=0$$

Now I'm not sure how to show that the difference is non-negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left|\int u_n v_n d \mu -\int uv d \mu\right| \leq\int |u_n v_n-uv| d \mu$$

Comment: Hey, thanks. on a related note, does the limit of the absolute value of a function always exist?

Comment: If exists $\lim f$ then also exist $\lim |f|$ since the absolute value is continuous.

Comment: al right. thanks :D